# GDAL's ReadAsArray() incredibly slow when reading an in-memory raster?

Tags: python, raster, gdal, grib, gdal-python-binding

So I have a script set up in a conda environment on macOS Catalina running python 3.7, I'll post a paraphrased version of it:

```
from osgeo import gdal
import numpy as np

grib_url = '/vsicurl/some_grib_url'
grib_ds = gdal.Open(grib_url)

translated_grib = gdal.Translate('', grib, **translate_kwargs)

reprojected_grib = gdal.Warp('', translated_grib, **warp_kwargs)

band1_arr = reprojected_grib.GetRasterBand(1).ReadAsArray()
```

Essentially, I'm getting a grib file from a URL, reading it in memory, cropping and retrojecting it in memory, pulling out a specific band, then converting it to a numpy array. However, the script will not finish in the terminal. It's been hung up for a couple hours without throwing any errors.

If I convert the band to an array *before* translating and retrojecting the entire grib, it will convert it fine (within about a minute).

I've tried setting environments with python 2.6, 2.7, 3.6, 3.7, and 3.8 and the problem persists. I've also tried various combinations of gdal/numpy versions as I've seen that's a common problem. I've also tried iterations of installing one before the other.

I don't think there's necessarily an error, but rather gdal is just really slow opening a VRT in memory? Has anyone had a problem similar to this or know a way to fix it?